# Overloading the << operator error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

Here is my class:

```
#ifndef CLOCK_H
#define CLOCK_H
using namespace std;

class Clock
{
    //Member Variables

    private: int hours, minutes;

    void fixTime( );

    public:
        //Getter & settor methods.
        void setHours(int hrs); 
        int getHours() const;
        void setMinutes(int mins); 
        int getMinutes() const; 

        //Constructors
        Clock(); 
        Clock(int);
        Clock(int, int);
        //Copy Constructor
        Clock(const Clock &obj);
        //Overloaded operator functions
        void operator+(const Clock &hours);
        void operator+(int mins);
        void operator-(const Clock &hours);
        void operator-(int minutes1);
        ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Clock &clockObj); //This however is my problem where i get the error C2804. Saying that it has to many parameters 
};
#endif
```

All this function is supposed to do is out the values of a clock at different times.

Comment: It has three parameters. It should have two.

Comment: For future reference, please don't use the code-highlighting backticks when you post a code block.  There is a separate button for that (or you simply indent each line with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 17):

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Clock &clockObj);
```

should be

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, Clock &clockObj);
```

defined OUTSIDE the class.

See here: [Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function)

Comment: Mostly right, but it doesn't _have_ to be defined outside of the class.

Answer (score 11):

```
 ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Clock &clockObj);
```

should be

```
 friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Clock &clockObj);
```

According to Stanley et al's C++ Primer (Fourth Edition pp 514):

> When we define an input or output operator that conforms to the
>   conventions of the iostream library, we must make it a nonmember
>   operator. We cannot make the operator a member of our own class. If we
>   did, then the left-hand operand would have to be an object of our
>   class type

Therefore, it is good practice to overload `<<` and `>>` as friend functions of the class.

Comment: Wow.. Thank you so much. I probably look really stupid. Thank you again.